# Starcounter query that returns base class only

Tags: starcounter

Lets assume we have the non abstract base class A, which has a specialized class B.
I now want to make a query that only returns instances of A, not B. Can this be achieved?

Comment: I assume you already have a query which returns A and B - might be worth posting your work so-far.

Comment: Yes I had a much more complex environment which I simplified into A and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2**

[Starcounter implements](https://github.com/Starcounter/Starcounter/wiki/SQL-Comparison-Predicates) operator `IS`, which allows to check if an object belongs to the given type. However, the check include children and thus does not help. Implementation of operator `IS NOT` is missing, which I found after I tested it in the latest version of Starcounter. 
There is a [ticket](https://github.com/Starcounter/Starcounter/issues/2742) in Starcounter's issue tracker about this.

So the answer to the question is: It is not possible to select objects of a base class without selecting objects of children classes using SQL in current version of Starcounter. The filter has to be implemented in C# during iteration over the query result. An example of application, which filters out objects of `B`:

```
using System;
using Starcounter;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Db.Transact(delegate {
            new A { name = "a1" };
            new B { name = "b1" };
        });
        foreach (A a in Db.SQL<A>("SELECT a FROM A a"))
            if (!(a is B))
                Console.WriteLine(a.name);
    }
}

[Database]
public class A {
    public String name;
}

public class B : A {
}
```

The result of the program execution the first time will be:

```
a1
```

Comment: I already had a C# filter, so I'll just stick with that for now. Thanks

Comment: @k_rus Couldn't you use `WHERE CAST(a AS B) IS NULL`?

Comment: @MartinTörnwall Thank you for suggestion. I believe it should work. Needs to be tested.